# Converting Unicode to Multibyte

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have smalll problem i want to convert unicode into Multi byte is there any way

Comment: Did you check wcstombs? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/

Comment: I think you will need to give us some more details. What unicode format do you have now and which multibyte encoding do you want to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::string NarrowString(const std::wstring& str, const char* localeName = "C")
{
  std::string result;
  result.resize(str.size());

  std::locale loc(localeName);

  std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc).narrow(
    str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size(), '?',  &*result.begin());

  return result;
}
```

It should use the current locale to convert the unicode string. For the caracters that do not belong in the codepage the '?' caracter is being used. Tested with Visual C++ 2005/2008.

Comment: Good, but how to detect if it was successfully converted or an '?' was used for a character? Round trip conversion??

Answer (score 5):

Three options offhand:

- [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw(VS.80).aspx)
- [WideCharToMultiBye](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx)
- [W2A macro](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/76c6ec95-6f0d-4c1e-99a8-b9a714c057d8/)

Comment: +1 for good resource. Can you share any resource to convert the reverse one? Means, from Multibyte to Unicode?

Answer (score 3):

wcstombs works beautifully for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases WideCharToMultiByte() will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450989.aspx) winapi function.

Answer (score 0):

use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450989.aspx)