# How to Convert unicode version of ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to convert Unicode version of  ReadDirectoryChangesW to support multibyte is that possible

Comment: Do you mean "convert the FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION::FileName member from Unicode to multibyte"? Use the answers to your previous question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525456/converting-unicode-to-multibyte

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cast a multi byte string into a unicode string by using this simple method

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

    template <typename inputtype>
    std::wstring            toUTF16String(const inputtype& input)
    {       
        std::wstringstream ss;
        ss << input;
        return ss.str();
    }
```

You can then use this acquired value in the unicode function.

Comment: Warning: (Assuming that inputtype is std::string or const char*): This converts each char individually, with the widen() method of the global locale's char_traits facet, and is thus unsuitable for any multibyte encoding.