# How do I convert an LPTSTR to an LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, lpcstr, lptstr

So the output of the function GetUserName() gives the username as a LPTSTR. I need to convert this to a LPCSTR, as I want the username to be the name of the an ftpdirectory.

```
TCHAR id [UNLEN+1];
DWORD size = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(id, &size); // this is an LPTSTR

FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,id) // 2d parameter should be an LPCSTR
```

The problem is that I need to convert the LPTSTR string to a LPCSTR string.  Now I know that:

*LPTSTR is a (non-const) TCHAR string and
LPCSTR is a const string.*

**But how do I convert a TCHAR to a const string?**

I should note I don't have a rich programming/C++ background, I should also note that I'm compiling in multi-byte, not unicode.

Comment: When not converting anything: GetLastError() returns: 12003 and InternetGetLastResponseInfo() returns:7771a9a8.

Comment: just to note, FTPCreateDirectory api takes LPCTSTR , so you could simply do FTPCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,&id)

Comment: GetUsername also takes a LPTSTR , and there you'd also take the reference of your tchar array.

Comment: Turns out I had FILE (not a directory) on my ftpserver that had the exact name of my username. So when I deleted that file, all worked fine. Thanks for your help nevertheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are compiling for multi-byte, not unicode you don't have to do anything. `LPTSTR` will convert implicitly to `LPCSTR` as it's just a `char*` to `const char*` conversion.

Comment: Thanks  very much for your reply, please see my comments under Matteo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not compiling for Unicode, `TCHAR`=`char`, so you don't need to convert anything. On the other hand, when compiling for Unicode you must perform a conversion; there are several alternatives for this, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525456/converting-unicode-to-multibyte).

Comment: Interesting, when I just do this: cout << FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,username) << endl; cout << GetLastError() << endl; The boolean turns 0 (indicating the function failed) and the Error message I recieve is: 12003. I can't find what this error means as it is not described on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: But if I'd say newstring = "directoryname" and then FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,newstring); it works. Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR id [UNLEN+1];
DWORD size = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(&id[0], &size); // this is an LPTSTR

FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,&id[0]);
```

This code should work in unicode or multibyte builds.

Comment: Thanks for your replies jonathon, but it still doesn't work. I get the exact same errors. But if I'd say newstring = "directoryname" and then FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession,newstring); it works...