# PWCHAR to string

Tags: c++, string, char

As title states, I need a way to convert a PWCHAR to a std::string. The only solutions I can find online are for the opposite conversion, so I'd really like it if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks!

This is in c++.

Comment: On Windows platform you can use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It states that page is unavailable.. any other documentation on it?

Comment: works for me as well.  try googling the function name.

Comment: C++ and all its variation of "strings" makes some days a nightmare!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304249.aspx), `PWCHAR` is declared as follows:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR, *PWCHAR;
```

What you want is [`std::wstring`, declared in `string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/).

```
const PWCHAR pwc;
std::wstring str(pwc);
```

`std::wstring` is very similar to `std::string`, as both are specializations of `std::basic_string`; the difference is in that `wstring` uses `wchar_t` (Windows `WCHAR`), whereas `string` uses `char`.

---

If you *truly* want a `string` (and **not** a `wstring`), the advised C++ way is to use [`use_facet`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/use_facet/) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525642/591495):

```
const std::locale locale("C");
const std::wstring src = ...;
const std::string dst = ...;
std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc)
    .narrow(src.c_str(), src.c_str() + src.size(), '?', &*dst.begin());
```

---

You may also separately convert to a multibyte C string and then use this to build your `std::string`. This is *not* the preferred way of doing this in C++, however. The function for doing this is [`wcstombs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/), as declared below:

```
size_t wcstombs ( char * mbstr, const wchar_t * wcstr, size_t max );
```

Since you're on Windows, you may also use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) for this step.

```
int WideCharToMultiByte(
  __in       UINT CodePage,
  __in       DWORD dwFlags,
  __in       LPCWSTR lpWideCharStr,
  __in       int cchWideChar,
  __out_opt  LPSTR lpMultiByteStr,
  __in       int cbMultiByte,
  __in_opt   LPCSTR lpDefaultChar,
  __out_opt  LPBOOL lpUsedDefaultChar
);
```

`LPSTR` is defined as follows according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#lpstr):

```
typedef CHAR *LPSTR;
typedef char CHAR;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have a much easier time using `std::wstring`, since that is also a wide-character string class. If you really want to use `std::string`, and convert from 2-byte characters to single- or multi-byte characters, you will need to use a function that does that conversion. [wcstombs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the ANSI C function for doing this. Your platform may provide alternatives.