# How to detect if W2A conversion is fully successful

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, mfc, atl

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525456/converting-unicode-to-multibyte) you can see that when you convert from Wide to Narrow some symbols may be replaced by `?`. How to detect those cases when W2A conversion is applied on a string. Round trip conversion is a way, but not fast. I guess  while converting W2A function should mark somehow that the conversion was not fully possible. How to get that information?

EDIT: For example in case of

```
int WideCharToMultiByte(
  UINT CodePage, 
  DWORD dwFlags, 
  LPCWSTR lpWideCharStr, 
  int cchWideChar, 
  LPSTR lpMultiByteStr, 
  int cbMultiByte, 
  LPCSTR lpDefaultChar, 
  LPBOOL lpUsedDefaultChar 
);
```

The last argument is telling what I need. What about W2A? How to detect the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check this out, use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly. You have an indication that default character was used there, and you have flags that affect conversion process.

`W2A` uses the same API with `dwFlags` of zero, and `lpUsedDefaultChar` of NULL, so information you need is just not queried at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about this. I need to detect the case for W2A conversion.

Comment: How do you know? Any source code, please? I need to know what is substitutes as default character too.

Comment: Source code is in Visual Studio's `\VC\atlmfc\include\atlconv.h`

Comment: Thanks. So both of them are null: int `ret = WideCharToMultiByte(acp, 0, lpw, -1, lpa, nChars, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: In addition, note that `W2A` is deprecated (ATL 3.0); the [more modern version is `CW2A`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx).